# is there a framework to build plugins for firefox, chrome, safari and IE at the same time?

Tags: jquery, xhtml, browser, plugins, cross-browser

I am trying to write a plugin for our company and want to use HTML, JS and CSS to build them. Is there a framework so I only have to build my plugins once and not have to build one for Firefox, one for Chrome, one for Safari and so on. Jetpack and Google Chromes extension engine seem very close to each other is there a framework or a compiler which alters the javascript code so it's compatible with more than one browser?

I want to use jQuery in the Plugins at least it would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's nothing like that I know of at the moment. Greasemonkey probably has the most potential but there's nothing IE will ever support that other browsers do, unless other browsers start supporting what IE does (WebSlices?) - there are rumors already that Opera might do that, and I think I've seen a Chrome plugin that enables WebSlices.

jQuery itself is compatible with all those browsers because Javascript engines are generally implemented to a certain specific RFC.